# document.getElementById().value gets stuck in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an image which call a function in javascript which calls another function to show a form in javascript as follows:

```
<img alt="" width="16px" onclick="clickEdit('## DataItem.GetMember("id").Value ##', '## DataItem.GetMember("c2").Value ##','##DataItem.ClientId##')" 
                    id="imgEditGrid" style="border-width: 0px;cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" src="SiteImages/insert.png" title="Introduir FacturaEmitidaID" />
```

And here goes the first javascript function:

```
  function clickEdit(id, id2, rowid) {
        alert(rowid);
        document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_rowId').value = rowId;
        alert("hello2????");
        document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_idFactura1').value = id1;
        alert("hello3????");
        showFormInsert(id, id2);
        alert("wtf????");
  }
```

My problem is simple; just the first alert is called, which means it gets stuck int he first document.getelementbyID(). Previously I had the same function without both of this documents.getelement and it worked fine so I imagine it has something to do with it.

I checked several times and id1, id2 and rowid have the proper values. Here you can find them:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="idFactura1" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="rowId" runat="server" />
```

Don't know what else to do.

Comment: check if ids not getting duplicated in html code. Like 'ctl00_MainContent_rowId' should be one throughout the document.

Comment: what is the value of rowid??

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. You use `rowid` and `rowId`.

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where we can reproduce the issue? There is some information missing, like how you have declared ctl00_MainContent_rowId.

Comment: It's already solved; either way ctl00_MainContent_rowId it's not something I declare, it's an easy automated way to make references and launch events. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
function clickEdit(id, id2, rowid) {
    alert(rowid);
    document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_rowId').value = rowid;  //Not rowId
    alert("hello2????");
    document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_idFactura1').value = id; //Not id1
    alert("hello3????");
    showFormInsert(id, id2);
    alert("wtf????");
}
```